# Fragment-based tabs -- possible to avoid creating new fragments on each change?

Tags: android, optimization, android-fragments, tabs

I have made a very simple fragment-based tab controller for my app.

```
        Fragment f = null;
        switch(index) {
            case 0:
                f = new AFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                f = new BFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                f = new CFragment();
                break;
        }

        if(f!=null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.pnlTabContent, f);
            ft.commit();
        }
```

These fragments are controlled by ActionBar-tabs:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("A").setIcon(R.drawable.tab_a).setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("B").setIcon(R.drawable.tab_b).setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("C").setIcon(R.drawable.tab_c).setTabListener(this));
```

This works well, my only problem is that I create new fragments for every tab change. This sounds inefficient. So my first thought was to simply create an array (`Fragment[] tabs`) in the main activity to keep the fragments in memory, and then replace the switch in the first code block with `Fragment f = tabs[index];`.

But I can't find any articles mentioning this problem, which leads me to believe that it is indeed common practice to instantiate new fragments every time. Is that right? Are there no ways of "buffering" the fragments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the application. You can definitely buffer/cache the fragments. I do exactly that in one of my apps. I only have 3 fragments so I store them in a variable for each. Then when I switch fragments, I can just reference them with those variables.

Now, there are scenarios where you don't want to do that because you may need to reload/refresh the data on the fragment and just re-creating it is more efficient that writing  extra code to handle the refresh scenario.

Another case where you don't want to cache it is when the fragments are very large and it would be more efficient to just recreate the fragment when needed rather than keeping everything in memory. (The classical performance vs. memory/storage problem).

Hope this helps you making a good decision on your implementation.